# pass 'this' to alertify

Tags: javascript, jquery, alertify

I want to use alertify.js after "finding" a button in a div with the class .removeRow

```
  $(".removeRow").find("button").click(function(){
            alertify.confirm("remove this field?", function (e) {
                if (e) {
                    // user clicked "ok"
                    $(this).closest(".agrRow").remove();
                }
            });     
  });
```

the problem is after I call alertify, I loose the value of "this".
How can I pass "this" into the alertify function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".removeRow").find("button").click(function(){
    var temp = this;
    alertify.confirm("remove this field?", function (e) {
        if (e) {
            // user clicked "ok"
            $(temp).closest(".agrRow").remove();
        }
    });     
});
```